# How call lockWindowUpdate using DelphiPrism

Tags: delphi, delphi-prism, oxygene

How can I call lockWindowUpdate using Delphi Prism?

Answer (score 4):

Before worrying too much about how to call it, I would think very carefully first about whether you really should or even need to call it.  [Raymond Chen has some very useful discussion points about LockWindowUpdate() and it's pitfalls that you may wish to consider](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070221-11/?p=27933).

**Edit**:

It is almost never the intention of anyone to call `LockWindowUpdate`

```
LockWindowUpdate(hwnd);
...
LockWindowUpdate(0);
```

Instead you probably meant to use `SetWindowRedraw`:

```
SetWindowRedraw(hwnd, false);
...
SetWindowRedraw(hwnd, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
[DllImport('user32.dll')]
class method LockWindowUpdate(handle: IntPtr): Boolean;
```

in a class